# Accept nth number of element into array and sum all the prime number which is into the array?

Tags: java, arrays

In this code user enter nth number of element which combination of all prime or not prime but I want to add or sum of only prime number...

```
public class prime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the size of an array");
        int abc = in.nextInt();
        int num[] = new int[abc];
        int a = 0, sum = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < num.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("enter the value" + (k + 1));
            num[k] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (num[i] % i == 0) {
                    a = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (a == 0) {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number is prime" + sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logical error in your program.
**1)**: in inner `for` loop if `a` is get set then it will always contains value `1`. Therefore you have to correct it. (i.e. reassign the value `0` to `a` after the statement `sum=sum+i` 
**2)**: `sum` should accumulate the values of array elements which are prime. Therefore `sum=sum+i` --> `sum=sum+num[i];`

Additionally in inner `for` loop, you can put the condition `j<sqrt(i)`  to reduce the run time of program. Assuming, you can perform all the necessary action in order to make the code runnable.